# GeoJSON.Net Serializing to valid GeoJson file

Tags: geojson, c#, .net

Using the GeoJson.Net lib, how do I serialize a GeoJson.Net.Geometry.MultiPoint to a VALID MultiPoint GeoJSON file?

All I can find is how to serialize a random Geometry object to a JSON file that cannot be read for instance in QGIS.

Comment: can you show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to serialize with no problem and view in both QGIS 2.18 and 3.2.1.

Using a modified version of the [GeoJSON.Net Multipoint serialization test](https://github.com/GeoJSON-Net/GeoJSON.Net/blob/master/src/GeoJSON.Net.Tests/Geometry/MultiPointTests.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Agema.Common;
using GeoJSON.Net.Geometry;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace geojson_serialize_example
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var points = new List<Point>
            {
                new Point(new Position(52.370725881211314, 4.889259338378906)),
                new Point(new Position(52.3711451105601, 4.895267486572266)),
                new Point(new Position(52.36931095278263, 4.892091751098633)),
                new Point(new Position(52.370725881211314, 4.889259338378906))
            };

            var multiPoint = new MultiPoint(points);


            var actualJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(multiPoint);
            // ReSharper disable once UseFormatSpecifierInInterpolation
            var outputFilePath = Path.Combine(TempFileHelper.GetTemporaryDirectory(),
                $"{Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")}.json");


            File.WriteAllText(outputFilePath, actualJson);

            Console.WriteLine($"GeoJson Geometry Written To: {outputFilePath}");
        }
    }
}
```

This produced:

```
{
    "type": "MultiPoint",
    "coordinates": [[4.8892593383789062, 52.370725881211314], [4.8952674865722656, 52.3711451105601], [4.8920917510986328, 52.369310952782627], [4.8892593383789062, 52.370725881211314]]
}
```

which I was able to view in QGIS:

[image]